# Test that only a single bit is set in Flags Enum

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, enum-flags

So I have a flags Enum

```
public Enum test
{
   test1 = 1,
   test2 = 2,
   test3 = 4,
   etc.
}
```

How can I test that one bit, and only one bit is set?

I've 100% done this before but my mind is not working this am!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To check that only a single bit is set in a number, the number must (by definition) be a power of two. As such, you can use the following to test:

```
int intVal = ((int)myEnumFlags);
bool singleBitIsSet = intVal != 0 && (intVal & (intVal-1)) == 0;
```

My favorite reference for this kind of thing:

http://aggregate.org/MAGIC

Comment: Please note that this won't work when `intVal == 0`. `0` has no bit set but `0 & -1 == 0`

Comment: "To check that only a single bit is set in a number, the number must (by definition) be a power of two." Unless it's `0` wich isn't a power of 2 but has not bit set.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM : you are right. Updated my answer. It might be more efficient to swap the order of the test, depending on which values are more likely.

Comment: made an extension using the code from this answer. can now write `enumvalue.IsSingleFlag` (in addition to `enumvalue.HasFlag`, which Comes with the framework)